# Use JSON_ARRAYAGG with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use `JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(...))` in Entity Framework Core but I don't know much how to trick Entity Framework Core to use this function with a custom `IQueryable<T>`.

Does anybody have any simple example how this can be achieved ?

I can not build a raw query because the `IQueryable` is built dynamically based on params, but my idea was to first build the `IQueryable<T>` and then somehow combine that with the given functions. Lets take a simple example of what I want to achieve:

```cs
var people = await db.People.Select(x => new Person { Name = x.Name, Surname = x.Surname }).ToListAsync();
```

This will translate to:

```
select name, surname from people;
```

I want to have:

```
select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("name", name, "surname", surname) from people;
```

One solution is to get the query from the `IQueryable` and do a nasty replace on the final string, but this does not seem a very good solution.

Is there any way I can modify the list of params on runtime without using replace function ?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to convert all the rows in `People` into a single JSON array where each element is a JSON object representing two of the columns in the row.  Just in case this is an X/Y problem, what is the point of doing that?  It seems to me that this would not be any better than your original simple query.  If you _really_ need to convert that result into JSON, wouldn't it be simpler to do that at the callsite once you have the data?

Comment: @KirkWoll yeah true in this case it does not make any difference, but I was just giving a simple example to illustrate my use case, in reality I have many tables using left joins, and the resultset can be quite big, so, my initial idea was that I can just return the json directly from db, this would help my app to just send back to the client the payload directly without doing serialization/deserialization on the app side and I guess less data coming from db as well.

Comment: You usually want to do work like serialization off of the db server since the "app side" can easily scale horizontally.  Why burden your hard to scale relational db?  Also, why do you think less data would be coming from the db?  JSON is less efficient than table rows; after all, each row has to repeat the "column" name in the form of the JSON property name.  (among other inefficiencies)

Comment: I am not planning to use this for every endpoint because I know this does not make much sense to be used everywhere, my intention was just to use it in one place. Regarding the number of records, what I meant is that if u have one-to-many relationship, then you end up having redundant values(cells) in the final result, while using JSON you omit that problem, the payload in general should be more lightweight. I still need to properly test it using both approaches to give a final verdict but to test it I need to find a way to build two endpoints with two approaches, and see how they perform

Comment: Ah, gotcha, thanks for elaborating, I'm following your reasoning now.

Comment: If you want to do this sort of thing, why are you using EF (Core) in the first place? EF is an object tracker. If you want to do raw SQL, or other custom formatting, you're better off doing raw calls, e.g. with ODE, or maybe Dapper. You could also use a stored procedure. [EF Core has support for raw calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw) but IMHO you could as well use something else than EF.

Comment: @JHBonarius I use entity framework and not raw SQL because that allows me to build the queries dynamically by working with Expressions. If I had to build the SQL manually it would be a pain considering the logic to build the whole query is complex and has a lot of other arguments to be taken into consideration during runtime.

Comment: Still, what you want is not the user case for entity framework. What you could do is use [projection](https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-projection) (with a protection model, or anonymous type) to get only the two columns, and let C# convert it to JSON. But the server method you are referring to is not tracking an entity, this not for an entity tracking framework.